# Cannot read next data row for the dataset

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

Complex stored procedure populates a table.

Then I have simple dataset from that table that displays SSRS report in preview mode. But once I deploy it to production - i got an error says "Cannot read next data row for the dataset..."

[image]
All report in a dashboard are fine except of just one. And it was working fine until today. And I dont understand what did I do? 
The only thing I was running the stored procedure a couple of times to refresh data in a table.

```
;WITH cte_yoyComparison
AS
        (
SELECT  b.YearNum,
        b.MonthNum, 
        b.MonthName,
        ISNULL(SUM(Premium),0) as Premium,
        ISNULL(sum(case when TransactionType IN ('Policy', 'Reinstatement') then 1 ELSE 0 END),0) as Bound

FROM    tblCalendar b  LEFT JOIN Test_Plaza_ProductionReport  a ON b.MonthNum=MONTH(a.EffectiveDate) AND b.YearNum=YEAR(a.EffectiveDate)
WHERE YEAR(EffectiveDate) <> 2017
GROUP BY    b.YearNum, 
            b.MonthName,
            b.MonthNum
            )
SELECT  ISNULL(a.Premium,0) as Premium, 
        c.YearNum,
        c.MonthNum,
        c.MonthName,
        (ISNULL(a.Premium,0) / ISNULL(b.Premium,1))-1 AS Ratio,
        ISNULL(a.Bound,0) as Bound  
FROM tblCalendar c  
    LEFT JOIN cte_yoyComparison a
    ON c.MonthNum=a.MonthNum
    AND c.YearNum=a.YearNum
    LEFT JOIN cte_yoyComparison b
    ON c.MonthNum=b.MonthNum
    AND c.YearNum - 1 = b.YearNum
WHERE
    c.YearNum<>2017
ORDER BY
    c.YearNum DESC
    ,c.MonthNum
```

There are something in a second SELECT statement that causes that error. But I  cant understand what!
I tried `SET NONCOUNT ON` at the begging of the code - didnt help. 
Also tried in a Report Manager change Processing Options to `Do not timeout report` - still no luck!

Comment: Does this help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180747/cannot-read-the-next-data-row-for-the-dataset-dataset3-conversion-failed-when

Comment: You are right. Something with Ratio column. If I remove it  - it works fine.
Will try to find out what is going on

Comment: I got it. Thanks man!!!